# Can I install the Amazon lens in 12.04?

Tags: software-installation, lenses, shopping-lens

I want to stay with the LTS release cycle but I would like to support Ubuntu with my Amazon purchases. Is there a way I can install the Amazon lens in 12.04?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really install the exact one that's on 12.10, but you can do this instead...

Run this to install:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:markjtully/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-lens-shopping-alternate
```

---

To uninstall:

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping
```